# Right way to create flicker video with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, flicker

For a science experiment, we need to develop a program that shows a flickering stimulus, say for instance, a flickering square in the screen. We decided to use C++ and OpenGL for such purpose. The approach is the following: we keep track of the frame count in a display function, when the frame count is an even number, we draw a square in the screen, whereas when it is an odd number we draw nothing. At the same time, we implemented a small function to keep track of the current FPS.

We are using Windows 10 with a NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3080 Ti GPU, and tested the code in 2 monitors: one with 144 Hz refreshing rate and another one with 60 Hz refreshing rate. When running the code in a 144Hz monitor without explicitly limiting FPS, the square flickers sometimes, and for most of the time it appears fixed. Our function to calculate FPS shows 144 FPS. However, when changing the scope of the window, say when moving the mouse pointer to the task bar, the window where the square is being shown flickers differently but FPS still shows 144. When running the code in a 60Hz monitor, the square flickers continuously and FPS is 60. When limiting explicitly FPS, say to 120 and running the code in a 144Hz monitor, the flickering is a bit more steady, but we still see that sometimes the square remains fixed although the FPS returned by our function is 120.

We therefore thought that the problem could be the way we draw and erase from one frame to the next, plus some other configurations of the GPU and/or the OS that we haven't thought of. Below is the code we use for that. Any hints will be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>    
#include <gl/GLU.h>    
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <time.h>

# define FPS 120

using namespace std;

bool limitFPS = false;

int initial_time = time(NULL), final_time, frame_count = 0;
int frameNum = 0;

void timer(int) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000/FPS, timer, 0);

}

void idle() {
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display() {
    // display callback function
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity(); // resets coordinate system

    // draw something here
    if (frameNum % 2 == 0) {
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f(-5.0, 5.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-5.0, -5.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(5.0, -5.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(5.0, 5.0, 0.0);
        glEnd();
    }
    glutSwapBuffers(); // presents buffer in the screen
    frame_count++;
    frameNum++;
    final_time = time(NULL);

    if (final_time - initial_time > 0) {
        cout << "FPS: " << frame_count / (final_time - initial_time) << endl;
        frame_count = 0;
        initial_time = final_time;
    }
}

void init() {
    // initializing window params
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);   
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    // set viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    // set projection   
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-10, 10, -10, 10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    cout << "Starting..." << endl;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);   
    glutCreateWindow("Test Window"); // first create the window, then register the callback
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); // how window reshape is going to be handled
    if (limitFPS)
        glutTimerFunc(1000/FPS, timer, 0); // function to perform animation, timer func will be called after X ms
    else
        glutIdleFunc(idle);
    init();
    glutMainLoop(); // requires a display callback: a function when the window needs to be drawn

    cout << "Finishing..." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the setting you're looking for is called v-sync but I don't know how to do it in GLUT

Comment: Are you sure that the problem on 144Hr monitors isn't just that the human vision doesn't see flickering at that speed? The only reliable way to check is when you record the screen also at 144Hz and check frame by frame.

Comment: @BDL good question. In another setup using Psychopy  (a Python framework to make experiments) we tried creating such videos and tested the flickering with a combination of oscilloscope and photodiode. We could verify that sometimes the flickering reaches the targeted frequency but other times not. Thus the decision to use something like OpenGL and C++. Our concern is that maybe we're missing something essential using OpenGL that the community would be aware of.

Comment: The only real problem I see is the cout, that will definitely cause the frame to take longer.

Comment: Windows uses a compositor, which from the sound of it may be interfering with your code. Creating a full-screen borderless window (like most games do) disables the compositor pipeline.